# tinyobj::attrib_t normals are empty after calling tinyobj::LoadObj?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, ray

Hi I am trying to load a 3D obj with textures and bump maps , however everytime I call  tinyobj::LoadObj() function it returns shapes with no normals and I need those to calculate the color with my ray tracer. 
Please help.

```
tinyobj::attrib_t attrib;
    std::vector<tinyobj::shape_t> shapes;
    std::vector<tinyobj::material_t> materials;
    std::string err;
    // Expect '.mtl' file in the same directory and triangulate meshes
    bool ret = tinyobj::LoadObj(&attrib, &shapes, &materials, &err,
                                (directory + filename + extension).c_str(), directory.c_str(), true);
```

Also here is the code I use to check if the normals are in place, it always return -1
`shape.mesh.indices[i].normal_index`